How to ask a good question for Cryptography.SE
Every now and then we will have new users and all welcome to ask questions ( and also provide answers - this is another subject).
Most of the time we see that the questions are weak

No background is given; CTF, homework, the source.
Only links provided to read, no page and paragraph or the better the quotation form the source are provided.
Too many questions ( a record was 28 question mark that I've seen)
The aim is missing,
and, so on..

So the question is How to write a good question on Cryptography.SE

The aim of this question is to discuss this subject then write a canonical one in an another Q/A.


The background should be provided as clearly as possible.
...

